# Problem deserializating XML multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I have this xml: [xml in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/k9k4CH8E)

and a XSD that I converted to a C# class with the VS DevTool:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class RTSLineItemAddRequest {

    private ARTSHeader aRTSHeaderField;

    private Transaction[] pOSLogField;

    private string majorVersionField;


    public ARTSHeader ARTSHeader {
        get {
            return this.aRTSHeaderField;
        }
        set {
            this.aRTSHeaderField = value;
        }
    }


    public Transaction[] POSLog {
        get {
            return this.pOSLogField;
        }
        set {
            this.pOSLogField = value;
        }
    }
```

But when it tries to deserialize I get an:

> `<RTSLineItemAddRequest xmlns=' not expected...`

If I remove the object `XmlTypeAttribute` and `XmlRootAttribute`, it deserializes without errors but the object POSLog is never read. What am I doing wrong?

I don't understand why DevTool overlooks `POSLog` and the object is `Transaction[]`, could you explain that to me?

I know I can read each node and parse but I want to do it in just one line. And also, learn about XML.

Comment: @RajuKomati Please don't add code formatting to text which is not code. The language name C#, for instance, is not code, and should not be formatted as such. See the FAQ [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/215552)

Comment: Can you please confirm that XML you've posted is the one actually represents your data? There are no nodes with "http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/' namespace in that sample - so either you posted wrong XML or ...

Comment: Yes, I have the xml based on the xsd (the three where included when it was generated) and the namespaces are from the xsd. I mean, POSLog is not finished but I wanted to show that POSLog also has multiple namespaces. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: The root node `<RTSLineItemAddRequest ...` is not in any namespace, because it has no default namespace attribute `xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"`.  The child node `<POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" ` does, but the root does not.  Therefore it cannot be deserialized to `RTSLineItemAddRequest` as the `XmlRootAttribute` specifies the root node must be in the `http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/` namespace.  If the root XML node looked like `<arts:RTSLineItemAddRequest ...` then it would be deserializable.

Comment: xsi is the default namespace.  Apparently you cannot use a schema location with xsi.   If you change from :  xsi:schemaLocation to :  arts:schemaLocation the error will go away.

Comment: I can't change the xml I received that is <RTSLineItemAddRequest xmlns:arts="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" because it is give by the server. I tried just for know how it woks to do what @dbc said. POSLog is read but not ARTSHeader.. jdweng as i said i only can change the declaration of the class. Is there any solution with RTSLineItemAddRequest class?

Comment: @cris - yes, probably.  But first, can you please [edit] your question to include a well-formed, complete XML sample?  The current XML has parse errors when I upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ because it seems to have been truncated.  You can simplify by omitting child elements, just be sure to include all the necessary closing tags so the file can be parsed successfully.

Comment: Hi! @dbc I have edit my post to add [https://pastebin.com/k9k4CH8E] I also tried [xmlvalidation.com] schemaLocation value = 'http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/RTSTransactionBeginV1.0.0.xsd' must have even number of URI's. I don't really know why if it is given by the server and I can't change it. Thank you for all your help